# How to get user data with SharedPreferences from RegisterActivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i programmed my register activity to get my user details and store it with `SharePreferences`

Now , im trying to get those values stored in the data to log in in my app but it seems im missing something, when i put anything in my edittexts in my login layout it logs in without checking the user

**RegisterActivity.class**

```
public class RegistrarUsuario extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button mBtnRegistrarUsuario;
    private TextView mRegistrarTxt;
    private EditText mUsername,mPassword,mSecondPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrar_usuario);

        mRegistrarTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo2);
        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombreUsuario);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.primeraContraseña);
        mSecondPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.segundaContraseña);

        Typeface fuente = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MrDafoe-Regular.ttf");
        mRegistrarTxt.setTypeface(fuente);


        mBtnRegistrarUsuario = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarUsuario);


        mBtnRegistrarUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("Reg",MODE_PRIVATE);
                String username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String secondpassword = mSecondPassword.getText().toString().trim();




                if(username.length()<=0){
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrarUsuario.this, "Ingrese un usuario.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else if(password.length()<=0){

                    Toast.makeText(RegistrarUsuario.this, "Ingrese contraseña.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else if(secondpassword.length()<=0){
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrarUsuario.this, "Confirme su contraseña.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                else if(password.equals(secondpassword)){

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
                    editor.putString("Username",username);
                    editor.putString("Password",password);
                    editor.putString("SecondPassword",secondpassword);
                    editor.commit();

                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrarUsuario.this, "Usuario creado con exito!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrarUsuario.this,PantallaPrincipal.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                else{

                    Toast.makeText(RegistrarUsuario.this, "No coinciden las contraseñas.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




            }
        });

    }
}
```

** LoginActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText mUsername,mPassword;
    private Button mLoginBtn,mBtnRecuperar,mBtnRegistrar;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private static String usuario ="admin";
    private static String contraseña="123";


    private final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";

    private final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contraseña);
        mLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo);


        Typeface fuente = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MrDafoe-Regular.ttf");
        mTextView.setTypeface(fuente);


        mBtnRecuperar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecuperar);

        mBtnRecuperar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RecuperarContrasenia.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mBtnRegistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrar);
        mBtnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrarUsuario.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });




        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("Reg",MODE_PRIVATE);
                String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                String userDetails = preference.getString(username + password + "data","No information on that user.");
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
                editor.putString("display",userDetails);
                editor.commit();

               if(mUsername.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 && mPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ){

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Los campos estan vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }else
               {

                   if(mUsername.getText().toString().trim().equals(username) && mPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(password)){

                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PantallaPrincipal.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                   }else{

                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Los campos son incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }




            }
        });


    }
}
```

i dont know what im missing that it dont verify the user if exists or login with the credentials i make in `RegisterActivity.class`

thanks

Comment: Here is a sample app for login.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never retrieving the username and password from `SharedPreferences`. And at the end you are checking the information the user puts in the TextEdits against itself so the validation always returns `true` to any non empty value.

Change this:

```
SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("Reg",MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
```

To this:

```
SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("Reg",MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = preference.getString("Username", "");
String password = preference.getString("Password", "");
```

Comment: i have just 1 more problem, it only log in with the latest user registered and not with more than 1 i register , what it should be ? @mikehc

Comment: I wouldn't recommend registering users against SharedPreferences or anything local based. Because as soon as the user uninstalls the app, all of that information will be gone. Is far from a recommended practice.

Let's say you are doing it for testing or as a proof of concept. What you can do is to use `SharedPreferences.getStringSet` and `SharedPreferences.Editor.setStringSet`. The idea is that you are going to have a `Set` with the combination of username and password. On Login you have to check against all the other combinations that you have save so far.

Comment: i know, im only using this for demo purposes